# Custom ListView adapter in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have an android app where i want to display some messages.The messages are classified into two categories, images and text.Text messages have two types,sent and received.I have created a custom listview adapter to display the messages in a listview.When calling the adapter,i pass an arraylist of 13 objects.Problem is not all the messages in arraylist are displayed.Only the first five messages are displayed.The messages are displayed three times each.When a message item in the listview is clicked,more than one message is highlited.What could be the problem.
Here is the listview adapter:

```
public class CustomMessageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<?> listData;

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomMessageListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_message,
                null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.incoming_message = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.received_layout);
        viewHolder.outgoing_message = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sent_layout);

        viewHolder.sent_message = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sent_messages_textView_message);
        viewHolder.sent_time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sent_messages_textview_time);

        viewHolder.sent_image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sent_image_imageview);
        viewHolder.received_image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.received_image_imageview);

        viewHolder.sent_image_layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sent_image_layout);
        viewHolder.received_image_layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.received_image_layout);

        viewHolder.received_message = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.messages_textView_message);
        viewHolder.received_time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.messages_textview_time);

        viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.messages_textView_date);

        viewHolder.sent_hepasnap = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.chat_layout_sent_hepasnap);
        viewHolder.recieved_hepasnap = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.chat_layout_received_hepasnap);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    MessageItem messageItem = (MessageItem) listData.get(position);
    Log.i("msg", "" + position);
    if (messageItem.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
        if (messageItem.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("sent")) {
            viewHolder.outgoing_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.sent_message.setText(messageItem.getMessage());
            viewHolder.sent_time.setText(messageItem.getTime());
        } else {
            viewHolder.incoming_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.received_message.setText(messageItem.getMessage());
            viewHolder.received_time.setText(messageItem.getTime());
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView sent_message;
    TextView sent_time;
    TextView received_message;
    TextView received_time;
    RelativeLayout outgoing_message;
    RelativeLayout incoming_message;
    RelativeLayout sent_hepasnap;
    RelativeLayout recieved_hepasnap;
    TextView date;
    ImageView sent_image;
    ImageView received_image;
    RelativeLayout sent_image_layout;
    RelativeLayout received_image_layout;
}

}
```

And when message is clicked:

[image]

Comment: Does the `Log.i("msg", "" + position);` print the correct positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add viewHolder.incoming_message.setVisibility(View.GONE); to if condition

(messageItem.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("sent"))

and  viewHolder.outgoing_message.setVisibility(View.GONE); to else condition.

If your Problem not solved then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the messages are getting displayed multiple times because they carry older values whenever convert view is non-null.

And since your incoming and outgoing messages are both getting filled it is giving the illusion of multiple items getting selected.

So you should change visibility of unused views to View.GONE.